# Grails: Intercept form request

Tags: grails

My Grails domain model consists of something like the following:

`Competition` - with name String property

`Club` - with name String property

`Team` - with club and competition properties

`Game` - with teamOne and teamTwo properties

I'm looking to create a `Game` form that contains the following:

- a competition drop-down
- a team one drop-down
- a team two drop-down

For my team drop-downs though I wish to just have a list of `Club` names e.g. `${Club.all}`

However, I then wish to have some ***interceptor*** that will use the `Competition` and `Club` name to construct the appropriate `Team` before the `Game` entity is constructed

I do not wish to introduce any Ajax/Javascript to my application, I want to keep the UI work as minimal as possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it a one-to-one relationship between team and club?

Comment: Why not just `Team.findByCompetitionAndClub(cometition, club)`?

Comment: @crudolf - because competition is selected at the same time as a team, so for your approach to work I'd need to use Ajax e.g. load team drop-down based on competition selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [beforeInterceptor](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) available in controllers. I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but it sounds like you can do what you describe.

Comment: You could also use a command object to intercept the form input and add a custom validator to the fields that need computed/calculated data. Command objects execute before any code in an action. A custom validator could call a service method or you could create a private method on the command object that does the heavy logic. Again, just some suggestions.